# c++ googletest handling exceptions within try-block

Tags: c++, googletest

When I start my gtest project with a structure like this, the code always breaks at the throw-statement, as if there is no try-catch around it. 
Is There a way of changing the behaviour to just go on in the catch-block?

```
void errornousFunction()
{
    try 
    {
        int i = 5;
        throw;
    }
    catch ( ... )
    {
        int i = 5;
    }
}

TEST(testCaseName,asdf)
{
    errornousFunction();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void errornousFunction()
{
    try 
    {
        int i = 5;
        throw i;
    }
    catch ( ... )
    {
        int i = 5;
    }
}
```

then u can try

Comment: is there an explanation for that behaviour? Might it be, because throw; only rethrows an exception and at that time there is actually none to rethrow?

Comment: Throwing an integer is a Very Bad Idea. Throw `std::exception` or a derived class.